# TestFlight does not accept my IPA which has AirshipKit.framework in Embedded Binaries

Tags: ios, xcode, urbanairship.com

When i put my IPA to testflight, it shows an error:

> ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for ***.app/Frameworks/AirshipKet.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."
>
> ERROR ITEM-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: '582UTB8G9R.com.urbanairship.AirshipKit' for the key 'application-identifier' in Payload/***.app/Frameworks/AirshipKit.framework/AirshipKit'"
>
> ERROR ITMS-90179: "invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/***.app/Frameworks/AirshipKit.framework/AirshipKit' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile."

It seems that it is the code sign error. But AirshipKit.framework is just a framework, and if i delete AirshipKit.framework in my project, it can successfully put to testflight.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to strip-out the architectures of the framework that Apple doesn't like.  You can use `lipo` for this.

Not tested (from memory).  **Make sure you keep a backup before doing this!**

```
$ lipo -remove x86_64 path/to/Airship.framework/Airship -output temp1
$ lipo -remove i386 temp1 -output path/to/Airship.framework/Airship
$ rm temp1
```

I assume that Xcode will resign the framework during the build process.

Finally, contact the developer of Airship and tell them to provide different frameworks for OSX and iOS.